# Why html5 is converted to unclosed tag?

Tags: html

I faced the following problem:

```
<header>
  <div id="test">test</div>
  <div id="sometest">sometest</div>
</header>
```

With browsers that doesn't support html5 they are converted like below:

```
<header></header>
<div id="test">test</div>
<div id="sometest">sometest</div>
```

I would like to know why they are converted like this?

Comment: Are you sure you are not having invalid HTML to begin with?

Comment: I faced the problem in ie8

Comment: Can you try adding the following script in the head of the document `<script>'article aside footer header nav section time'.replace(/\w+/g,function(n){document.createElement(n)})</script>`?

Comment: @PeeHaa I inspected and it's working now with your script!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older user agents that don't support HTML5 tags have no idea about what those tags are, mean or how they should behave. In order to fix this you can add the following script in the head section of you pages:

```
<script>'article aside footer header nav section time'.replace(/\w+/g,function(n){document.createElement(n)})</script>
```

This snippet creates the elements in the DOM. ANother thing you probably have to do is style the new element to behave like they should. I.e. `header { display: block; }` etc.